# Jenkins logs for a perl build file

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

Today I started working with jenkins and I successfully added my projects to jenkins and it says all works fine . one of the build takes more than 5 hours but didn't finish either so aborted it(while manual build takes less than 1 hour).. and while i tried to check with the log the log was not detailed. so i tried to get the logs of the perl script by running it as a shell command

```
         usr/local/bin/perl perlscript.pl>logfile.txt
```

there was no log written and there was no evidence of the build triggered either cases.i'm not aware of what the problem is as both the perlscript(works fine while manually triggered) and jenkins are working properly except this project. I would like to have your help.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things you should understand about Jenkins:

- Jenkins shows STDOUT as the log of the Job,
  so if you redirect it to a file - nothing will be shown in the log.
- Depending on how you have set it up, Jenkins may run as its own user,
  which may change the behavior of your scripts.
  You can confirm this by echo-ing the username at the beginning of your *Execute Shell* block,
  for example:
  `echo $USER`
- Each Jenkins-Job is run from its own workspace -
  you can confirm that location by simply printing the current working directory
  at the beginning of your *Execute Shell* block, for example:
  `echo my current directory is`
  `pwd`